# How to insert two Arraylist values into the database table at the same time and in same query

Tags: java, loops, insert, arraylist

I have Two ArrayList which i have to insert into the database .I have the code for inserting one arraylist values in the database...Here is  my first  arraylist for inserting values in the database

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    int d = (int) list.get(j);
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into cdrcost  (calldate) value ('" + d+ "'));
}
```

Now as per my need i have another arraylist to insert into the database within the same query that i mentioned here.So i need any path so that the values of both these arraylist be inserted into the database ..
Any help will be highly appreciated...
Thanx in advance...

Comment: What do you mean with "within the same query"? You can use the above code for both lists. What's your problem with that?

Answer (score 3):

```
PreparedStatement psth = dbh.prepareStatement("insert into cdrcost  (calldate) value (?)");
for (List<Integer> lst: Arrays.<List<Integer>>asList(list1,list2))
  for (int value: lst) {
    psth.setInt(1,value);
    psth.addBatch();
  }
psth.executeBatch();
```

if you need to set more than 1 value:

```
PreparedStatement psth = dbh.prepareStatement("insert into cdrcost  (calldate, othercolumn) value (?, ?)");
Iterator<Integer> it1 = list1.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> it2 = list2.iterator();
for (; it1.hasNext() && it2.hashNext();) {
  psth.setInt(1,it1.next());
  psth.setInt(2,it2.next());
  psth.addBatch();
}
psth.executeBatch();
```

Comment: @MiljenMikic Thanx sir for quick response..I have multiple columns and multiple arraylist then how to insert ..sir plz guide in this case

Comment: I don't follow you. Do you have 2 array lists, which have to be used in order to feed the query "insert into sometable (column1, column2) values (valueFromList1, valueFromList2)"?

Comment: @jdevelop Thanx sir i am using for loop is it possible to iterate many arraylist into forloop and insert into query